# What is Karna's caste (varna)?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system, karna

What is [Karna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna)'s [varna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varna_(Hinduism)) (caste)? A [Kshatriya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshatriya) by birth, then assumed a different one after being raised by foster parents (belonging to a different varna) and finally reclaimed it?

Who all (during the Mahabharata time) knew of Karna's true identity and his varna due to birth?

Comment: His birth is of anulOma type. Father was Surya - a Divinity and hence highest available caste is brahmana and his mother was Kunti -a kshatriya.  Hence, if birth based type is accepted,  then he must be a brahmana. Very few people knew of his identity

Answer (score 5):

- His mother was Kshatriya (Kunti) that is why He has been considered as Kshatriya.
- He brought up as child of chief charioteer of King Dhritrashtra.
- As per Mahabharata, Parshurama only taught to Brahmins but When Parshurama go to know that  Karna is a **Kshatriya**, Parshurama laid curse upon Karna.

Sources :

1. [Karna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: TV serials are not an acceptable source on this site, because they tend to take a lot of artistic license.  It's best to give a citation to a specific chapter of Vyasa's original Mahabharata: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm

Comment: Varna are decided by quality not by birth

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

In theory, he was of **Karna** identity.

- For practical purposes he was **Kshatriya**
- Considering his adoptive parents, he was **Suta**

#### Theory

His actual name was "Vasusena" or "RAdheya", after his adoptive mother "Radha".

> And seeing the child furnished with bright mail and golden ear-rings, the twice-born ones named him Vasusena.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03307.htm)

However, it's noted (at least in BRC Mahabharata) that Bhishma [& possibly Vidura] knew the correct identity of RAdheya already. For experienced & knowledgeable person like them, it would have been easy to match his attributes with his biological mother Kunti, whose other sons were 5 PAndavas.
My assumption is that, Karna would have possibly named so by such dignitaries only.

#### Logic

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19310/1049), Kunti herself was adopted by her father. Her biological father Sura was from the *Vaishya* class.

Kunti was married to the king PAndu, who was from Kshatriya class. Hence all her sons, were considered *PAndava*-s:

- Vasusena/RAdheya -- who was abandoned by her before marriage, and adopted by Adhiratha & RAdha
- Yudhishthira, Arjuna, Bhima -- her biological children
- Nakula, Sahadeva -- children adopted by Kunti, after the death of her biological mother MAdri

A child born to a Kshatriya (PAndu) and a Vaishya (Kunti) is considered as "Karna". This was applied to Yuyutsu.

> During that year, O king, was begotten upon her by the illustrious Dhritarashtra a son endued with great intelligence who was afterwards named Yuvutsu. And **because he was begotten by a Kshatriya upon a Vaisya woman, he came to be called Karna**. [Above linked answer]

#### Clarification

However it's clarified that why Vasusena was named as Karna. So it's quite likely that above theory may not have any support and is wrong.

> The son of Surya was before this known by the name of Vasusena. But since he cut off his natural armour, he came to be called Karna (the cutter or peeler of his own cover). [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm)

---

#### Kshatriya

Usually a son carries his biological father's class. However in the case of Niyoga, the son carries his adoptive father's class, which could be PAndu in this case. With that logic, Yudhishtira, Bhima, Arjuna could also be considered "Karna"-s, to be precise. Because all of them were born to Kunti from certain celestial deity.

If we consider that, Kunti's own class was changed to Kshatriya after her adoption, then all PAndava-s were Kshatriya-s.

### Suta

Karna specifically always recognised himself with his adoptive parents, as discussed [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14173/1049) hence he was considered as *Suta*, usually helpers to the Kshatriya kings.

> And it came to pass that at this time a Suta named Adhiratha, who was a friend of Dhritarashtra, came to the river Ganga, accompanied by his wife.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03307.htm)

Suta is a subclass, which originates, when a Kshatriya man begets a child to a Brahmana woman:

> If a Kshatriya begets a son upon a Brahmana woman, such a son, **without being included in any of the four pure orders**, comes to be regarded as a **Suta** The duties of a Suta are all connected with the reciting of eulogies and encomiums of kings and other great men.

Comment: "Her biological father Sura was from the Vaishya class"- u mean to say Krishna's grand father was from the Vaisya class... Don't u think he was from Vrashni clan of Yadavas who were Kshatriyas...

Comment: Irrespective of where and by whom he was raised, he will remain a Kshatriya by birth.

Comment: "For experienced & knowledgeable person like them, it would have been easy to match his attributes with his biological mother Kunti, whose other sons were 5 PAndavas." No, he came to know about Karna's identity through Narad Muni.

Comment: Who was the biological father of Karna? It cannot be Surya/Sun, the deity. [It might be Durvaasa](http://www.boloji.com/index.cfm?md=Mobile&sd=Articles&ArticleID=1439), a brahmana. Then he's the offspring of a vaisya mother (varna of Kunti, as you say) and a brahmana father.

Comment: @sv. As per scriptures it was the sun. At death Karna merged back to sun. It was apparently possible to invoke any natural deity in its spiritual form as human. Though this subject is about belief. We may not know that science of that time today; like how they didn't have knowledge of today's test tube babies. Very few people like Kunti has used such technique as per sources.

Comment: 'As per scriptures it was the sun' - but scriptures do not talk about varna of an offspring of God and human, there's already lot of confusion due to intermixing of humans. Introducing new varnas for mixture of humans and Gods based on mythology makes it even more messy. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: @sv., that's why I menioned that in special case of Niyoga the varna of biological father isn't considered. Take example sage VyAsa's children DhritarAshtra & Pandu who were still Kshatriya.

Comment: @iammilind Kunti's biological father Surasena was a Kshatriya; he was a descendant of the lunar dynasty king Vrishni.  See this chapter of the Srimad Bhagavatam: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/24/chapter-view

Comment: @sv. Karna was the son of Surya and Kunti.  The son of a Deva and a human has the same caste as the human.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "The son of a Deva and a human has the same caste as the human" - source for this claim?

Comment: @sv. When a human and a non-human have a child, the child takes the caste of the human, since the non-human doesn't have a caste.  There are countless instances of this in Hindu scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "There are countless instances of this in Hindu scripture" - that's not going to do it, please cite a verse from the smritis stating the rule.

Comment: "Considering his adoptive parents, he was Shudra" -- even his adoptive parents were not Shudra..They were Suta..

Comment: @YDS, corrected. There is a big difference between "Shudra" and "Suta". It's worth noting down what is "Suta" in detail. Added in the answer.

Comment: You are all wrong Varna is decided by quality not Birth  Bhagvad Gita 18.41: The duties of the Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas, and Shudras—are distributed according to their qualities, in accordance with their Skills (and not by birth).

Answer (score 0):

Varna is decided by quality not by birth

If you are a seeker teacher or guru you are bharaman
If you are solder, diplomat, government official you are a shatria
If you are business man, farmer you are a vaiya
If you are a labour you are a shudra
It doesn't mean you can only have same quality
You can change your Profession anytime

> Bhagvad Gita 18.41: The duties of the Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas, and Shudras—are distributed according to their qualities, in accordance with their Skills (and not by birth).
>
> Bhagvad Gita 18.42: Tranquility, restraint, austerity, purity, patience, integrity, knowledge, wisdom, and belief in a hereafter—these are the intrinsic qualities of work for Brahmins.
>
> Bhagvad Gita 18.43: Valor, strength, fortitude, skill in weaponry, resolve never to retreat from battle, large-heartedness in charity, and leadership abilities, these are the natural qualities of work for Kshatriyas.
>
> Bhagvad Gita 18.44: Agriculture, dairy farming, and commerce are the natural works for those with the qualities of Vaishyas. Serving through work is the natural duty for those with the qualities of Shudras.

Karna was a Kshatriya as by his quality

Comment: Your answer appears to be advocating guna-based based varna system but my question is about Karna's birth-based varna. Read the last line of my question again, 'Who all (during the Mahabharata time) knew of Karna's true identity and his **varna due to birth**?'

Comment: You can not ask someone Verna on birth based as it's a quality that's doesn't make any sense you are asking what is the profession of a Person if his father was a teacher does it make any sense?