# If ShriKrishna knew Karna and Arjuna are brothers, why did not he stop their fight?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, karna

ShriVishnu knows everything, yet He lets Pandavas and Karna be at fight. Moreover, Karna, born to ShriSurya, the Illuminator of whole Universe, had to suffer worse than the most unfortunate mortal.

Comment: Everybody suffers for their past misdeeds. God does not interfere in that matter. You do good you get good. You do bad you get bad. Simple!

Comment: In Hinduism Gods like Vishnu, Shiva, Brahma are roles. They have to do their duty and do not have power over the Brahman which creates worlds for its selfish desire to grow. Contrary to the Indian thought of omnipotent Vishnu or Shiva could have stopped the war but didn't, they could not have stopped the war even if they wanted to.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande then why is it said- Chant name of God, it is sin remover. Even in devi bhagwat it is said- if one kills all beings, and then even chants the name of Devi once, he will not be attached to any sin.

Comment: yes, in Kali Yuga, chanting name of God removes sins. But Karna lived in Dvarapa Yuga :)

Comment: @AnuragSingh If God's Name is chanted with Faith,surrender and without offense it delivers a person even from most abominable sin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Karna choose not to fight on the side of the Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11797/why-did-karna-choose-not-to-fight-on-the-side-of-the-dharma) Krishna did persuade Karma to fight for PAndava-s. But Karma declined due to obligations towards Duryodhana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Krishna tried to](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05140.htm).
*Sama, Dana, Bheda, Danda* - neeti - are the 4 types of bringing about reconciliation between two enemies, to be followed in that order preferably.

When Duryodhana said he wouldn't return Pandavas kingdom after 13 years as per agreement during Dice game, Pandavas send Krishna as messenger to Kauravas to talk samadhaan (diplomatic dialogue). When Duryodhana refuses, Krishna asks him to gift (Dana) 5 cities, or 5 villages, or 5 houses, or at least a house with 5 rooms. He still refuses.

Now, Krishna knows Duryodhana is ready to go to war because he feels he can rely on Karna as his biggest strength/weapon. So, Krishna goes to Karna, tells him the true story of his birth, that his mother is Kunti, and Pandavas are his younger brothers, and asks him to join his side (Bheda)

Karna however says he is 'indebted' to Duryodhana since he gave him Anga desh as gift during Pandavas 'graduation' ceremony where Karna was insulted that he could not participate in Dhanur Vidya exhibition/competition, as he was charioteer's son.
So, he refuses to join Pandavas' side.

So finally, Krishna takes up punishment (Danda), and orchestrates Kurukshetra war.

Also, just because two people are brothers does not mean they should not fight if one of them is doing Adharma. In previous Avatara, Shri Rama showed this twice - Vali vs. Sugriva, Vibhishana vs. Ravana. He didn't tell Sugrive that he should not fight with his brother Vali, or Visbhishana that he should not fight with his brother, Ravana.. because Rama always takes side of Dharma, irrespective of being one's brother or any other relation.

We all have free will.
God can show us the path, but if we refuse to walk the path, he won't force us to.

Answer (score 0):

Sri Krishna's main task was total annihilation of the Kshatriya race that was predestined towards the end of Dwapara and beginning of Kaliyuga. Kshatriya race wielded so much power that Krishna did not want to leave them to misuse that power in kalyuga. The later Kshatriays were conceived with brahmana men and Kshatriya women and were not as powerful as the ones that were annihilated.
In Stree Parva of Mahabharata of Veda Vyasa, Gandhari is distraught after viewing the dead bodies in Kurukshetra after the battle. In anger and grief over the death of her sons and the Kaurava soldiers, Gandhari curses Krishna with the death of all Yadavas in a manner similar to the death of her sons. She blames Krishna for his inaction and believes that he could have prevented the war and the slaughter of hundreds of millions people who died in the war.
Krishna's answer is interesting.
This is from Mahabharata, Book 11, Stree Vilapa Parva, Section 25 (translation by Kisari Mohan Ganguli):
 "Hearing these words, the high-souled Vasudeva, addressing the venerable Gandhari, said unto her these words, with a faint smile, ‘There is none in the world, save myself, that is capable of exterminating the Vrishnis. I know this well. I am endeavouring to bring it about. In uttering this curse, O thou of excellent vows, thou hast aided me in the accomplishment of that task. The Vrishnis are incapable of being slain by others, be they human beings or gods or Danavas. The Yadavas, therefore shall fall by one another’s hand.’ After he of Dasharha’s race had said these words, the Pandavas became stupefied.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. You should cite sources to back your answer. There were many Kshatrya remaining after the annihilation you are talking about. Parikshita was one of them.